# How to solve "data undefined" issue in ajax success?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, controller, form-submit

I have a JSP page, in which i have a button onclick of which I am calling an Ajax method called "sendmail()".And the send mail API is written in the Controller.I am trying to show an alert message in Ajax success with data.message and it says that data is undefined.

I tried to set the response object in the controller with message string as success and return it as string.
Note : To do this, i have to change my controller sendmail method to String return type .So i have observed that the Ajax calls doesnot enter the success method in this case.It works fine when the method is of type void.And when i checked with the help of chrome developer tolld,the network call returns 404(not found).The mail is succesfully being sent but the ajax success is not working.

This is my button and Ajax method,

```
<div class="uk-width-large-2-5">

  <div class="uk-form-row">
  <label>Message</label>
  <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="4" class="md-input"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-form-row">
  <button type="submit" class="md-btn md-btn-success md-btn-large" onclick="sendMail()">Send Message</button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**Ajax method :**

```
<script>
function sendMail() {
 var reqJson = {};
 reqJson.msg = $("#message").val();


$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "sendMail",
data : JSON.stringify(reqJson),
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json",
  success : function(data) {    
  console.log("data :"+data.message);
               }
 error: function()
 {
}
    });                                 
}
</script>
```

**Maincontroller.java**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMail", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
   public void sendContact(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String payload) {
        JSONObject jRespObj = new JSONObject();

      try {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        JSONObject jPayload = new JSONObject(payload);
         System.out.println("jobj : "+jPayload);
         String message = jPayload.getString("msg");
         InputStream inputStream = UserController.class.getResourceAsStream("/Contactusrequest.htm");
      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      try {
          IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer);
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        String from = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
        String to ="xyz@abc.com";
        String emailContent = writer.toString();
        emailContent = emailContent.replace("replaceMeFromEmail",from);
        emailContent = emailContent.replace("replaceMeToEmail", to);
        emailContent = emailContent.replace("replaceMeReason", message);

         emailClient.sendMail("", to, null, "Contact Us Request", emailContent);
        jRespObj.put("message", "Mail sent successfully");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

     } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
     }
    return jRespObj.toString();
   }
```

I want to get the response object from controller to Ajax success, to access the data.message.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.** You are returning the response, so in Ajax getting the data is undefined error. 
**Instead of returning Write the json response in body using the Gson or JSONObject.**

For example.

```
//Write the json response in body
  //return jRespObj.toString();
  response.getWriter().write(jRespObj.toString());
```

**Solution 2** - remove all other System.out.println statement and display the single response in json like.

```
System.out.print(jRespObj.toString());
```

In ajax you can get the response like

```
$ajax({
----
success : function(data) {    
  console.log("data :"+data['message']);
},
 error: function()
 {
}
```

Comment: I tried it sir,I am getting an error like this: "The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)."

Comment: Hi, you already using JSONObject so no need to convert in json. Instead of returning just Write the json response in body. I update my code please check

Comment: I have made the changes sir ,but the issue still persists.

Comment: set response.setContentType("application/json"); and then write response.getWriter().write(jRespObj.toString()); I tried it's working for me

Comment: Hi, you can also try.  remove all other System.out.println statement and display the single response in json.  //return jRespObj.toString(); System.out.print(jRespObj.toString());

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :
I added @Responsebody and parsed the data received in Ajax success.And here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendMessage" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String sendMessage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String payload) throws JSONException, IOException {
    JSONObject jRespObj = new JSONObject();
      try {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
     JSONObject jPayload = new JSONObject(payload);
     System.out.println("jobj : "+jPayload);
     String message = jPayload.getString("message");
     InputStream inputStream = UserController.class.getResourceAsStream("/Contactusrequest.htm");
     StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
     try {
      IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer);
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

       String from = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
       String to ="xyz@electronosolutions.com";
       String emailContent = writer.toString();
       emailContent = emailContent.replace("replaceMeFromEmail",from);
       emailContent = emailContent.replace("replaceMeToEmail", to);
       emailContent = emailContent.replace("replaceMeReason", message);
       emailClient.sendMail("", to, null, "Contact Us Request", emailContent);
       jRespObj.put("message", "Mail sent succesfully");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
    }
      return jRespObj.toString();
  }
```

**Ajax method:**

```
<script>
    function sendMessage() {
        console.log("page load");
        //$("#sendMessage").submit(function(e){

       // e.preventDefault();

        var reqJson = {};
        reqJson.message = $("#message").val();
        console.log(reqJson.message+"    jhgczjdhgbdzjvh");
         $.ajax(
         {
             url : "sendMessage/",
             type: "POST",
             data : JSON.stringify(reqJson),
             contentType: "application/json",
             success:function(data)
             {
                var msg = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(msg);


                UIkit.notify('<a href="#" class="notify-action">Clear</a> ' + msg.message, {
                 pos : 'top-center',
                 status:'success',
                 timeout : 2000
               });

              setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 2000);
             }, 
             error: function(data)
             {

               UIkit.notify('<a href="#" class="notify-action">Clear</a> ' + "Mail not sent", {
                 pos : 'top-center',
                 status:'warning',
                 timeout : 6000
               }); 
             }
           });

        }
 </script>
```